# Angular reactive form validation through formGroup + ngModel usage: Fatal warning of deprecation + removal of support?

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I've got a simple text input on my webpage HTML that I want to include dynamic form-validation on the input as follows:

```
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Chosen Name:</mat-label>
      <input name="chosenName" formControlName="chosenName" [(ngModel)]="chosenName" matInput type="text" placeholder="JOHN DOE"/>
      <mat-hint align="end">REQUIRED FIELD!</mat-hint>
      <mat-error *ngIf="hasNameError('chosenName', 'required')"
        >Minimum and Maxmimum of length 12 is required!</mat-error
      >
    </mat-form-field>
```

`chosenName` is a string variable declared in my component.ts which i take in thru [(ngModel)] 
*at least I'm sure thats how it works*

Everything runs fine, and I'm able to get the validator working. My only worry is that console shows this error:

```
It looks like you're using ngModel on the same form field as formControl. 
    Support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with 
    reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and will be removed 
    in Angular v7.
```

Is this something in particular i should be worried about? And if so, could someone kindly point me to a better implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is due to using the attribute formControlName and ngModel in the same HTML tag.

In case you are using Angular Forms, you should stick just with the formControlName since that is already mapping the values. Here's an example of how to use it

---

.html

```
<form [formGroup]="profileForm">

  <label>
    First Name:
    <input type="text" formControlName="firstName">
  </label>

  <label>
    Last Name:
    <input type="text" formControlName="lastName">
  </label>

</form>
```

---

.ts

```
profileForm = new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl(''),
    lastName: new FormControl(''),
});
```

Source: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

If you are not using angular forms you should just remove the formControlName attribute and it won't complain

Comment: I know this is a separate question, but do you know how i could capture the input value into a variable then, using formControl? I.e. set this.chosenName = input

Comment: If you want to to get the attribute firstName of your form you can get it from this.profileForm.value.firstName or subscribe to this.profileForm.valueChanges Observable that would be triggered every time an input of your form is modified

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are harming it anyway, but its always good practice to avoid doing this.
Always use FormGroup when you have lots of controls to work on in single page.